# Android - ViewPager: Tabs with fixed positions

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm using ViewPager to create a tab layout. It works ok but I want to change it's behavior a bit. When I swipe to a new tab it's title is moved to the center of the width forcing the titles of the other tabs to look kind of compressed. I want all tab titles to remain in a fixed position. I tried modifying the layout a little but I didn't get anywhere... How can I achieve this?

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:textColor="#2FB3E3"
    app:footerColor="#2FB3E3"
    app:footerLineHeight="1dp"
    app:footerIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    app:footerIndicatorStyle="underline"
    app:selectedColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:selectedBold="true"
    />
<com.bill.deuterh.NoSwipeViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You probably need to use `TabPageIndicator` instead of `TitlePageIndicator`...

Comment: Hello, did you manage to find a solution for this ? using TabPageIndicator won't help

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a fragment instead of declaring all in xml? In java file you can have more flexibily, and fragments can be reused..

For a complete example using fragment, you can read here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant. I'm allready using fragments for each of the tab activities. How else would I make it work? My problem is not with the activities. it is with the way the titles are shown ABOVE the activities